# How to specify default UI for Paypal checkout page

Tags: paypal

We're using Paypal Name-Value Pair API. As I see, there are at least 3 display styles:

1 - Paypal Account first
[image: Paypal Account first]

2 - Guest/CC first
[image: Guest/CC first]

3 - So modern layout
[image: So modern layout - I like this one best]

Do you know anyway to pick one of them as default theme?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal is in the process of testing and rolling out #3 to all payment flows, but they are not there quite yet.

Sometimes, depending on the situation, variables passed, buyer/seller country, other factors, it will default back to #1 or #2.

If going to #1 or #2, you can control which one of those screens defaults by passing a couple of variables in the `SetExpressCheckout` call:

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

SolutionType allows Guest Checkout (Paying with a CC without signing up for PayPal). LandingPage=Billing will default (if the classic view is used) to the Guest Checkout portion (#2 above). Passing `Login` instead of `Billing` will default it to #1.

Comment: Thank you so much, @PayPal_MSI_Robert.  I think your answer provided enough information about the question I've posted.